# I need a software that lets me create an excel spreadsheet with mp3 file names and their descriptions

Tags: database, search, microsoft-excel, mp3, filenames

What I mean by that, is something which plays me a sound file, lets me describe it, plays the next one, you get the point. And until the folder ends. When all of this is done, it generates a excel spreadsheet/database thingy that is easily searchable. For instance, if I have 300 files with movie quotes but named like BATMAN_REVENGE_1 it is not easy for me to find stuff. If I could do a quick search, for instance searching "be back" would result in TERMINATOR_MEMORABLE_3. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you thought of running speech recognition on each ans storing the results in `original_file_name.txt` which would save you a **lot** of typing.

Comment: Not easily searchable, and speech recognition... well... it is not _perfect_ yet.

Comment: Ever heard of grep, grin, find, etc. very easily searchable, (and no need to start/own excel), speech recognition has come on a long way and even if the results are 90% it is a lot quicker updating something nearly right than typing it all in from scratch. You could also collate it to Excel or a database later.

Comment: Windows guy here, so grep is not my book.

Comment: Wingrep or on Windows 10 Bash grep!